# Creating WSDL output from PHP DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom, wsdl

I'm new here so, bear with me. I'm trying to create a WSDL files from PHP DOM and i'm using this for my tags:

```
$element = $XMLDoc->createElement( 'soap:bodysec');
$XMLDoc->appendChild($element);
$element = $XMLDoc->createElement( 'ns:line', text');
$XMLDoc->appendChild($element);
```

This gives me:
      `<Bodysec/>
      <Line> Text </line>`

I would like

```
<bodysec>
<Line> Text </line>
<\bodysec>
```

How do I accomplish that ?

Comment: When it shows just `Text`, if this is on a web page then view the source as the other parts may just be considered as markup.

Comment: *btw* You should  `DOMDocument:createElementNS()` to create elements with a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding in the second element, you are just appending it to the document and not to the newly created `<bodysec>` element....

```
$XMLDoc->appendChild($element);
```

You need to make sure where you add in any new element...

```
$bodysec = $XMLDoc->createElement( 'soap:bodysec');
$XMLDoc->appendChild($element);
$line = $XMLDoc->createElement( 'ns:line', 'text');
$bodysec->appendChild($line);
```

One thing I tend to do is to use the tag name for the variable I assign to, this helps as you can see in the last line it shows the logic of adding the line to the bodysec elements.

Comment: Changed the 2nd line to :

     $XMLDoc->appendChild($bodysec);

Then it worked the way I wanted. Thanks